# Is it safe to use a disabled user to start a process in Linux?

Tags: linux, python3, uwsgi

I created the user `uwsgi` and the group `uwsgi` for using them as `uid` and `gid` in .ini-file for uwsgi properties. I didn't set password for this user (didn't run `sudo passwd uwsgi`, actually, I can't login as uwsgi). It is safe to use the user as a process owner for uwsgi processes? Or it is a bad practice and it is better to set a password for the user `uwsgi`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and it is pretty much standard practice.   Many daemons, for example, are run with their own dedicated username/uid (and, often, a dedicated gid) - they have no password (or a disabled password) and can't log in, but processes and cron jobs can be run with their UID.

Many of them also have `/bin/false` or `/usr/sbin/nologin` or similar as their shell.

e.g. on my Debian system, users `tftp` and `unbound` are used to run `tftpd` and the `unbound` dns resolver.  One of them has `/bin/false` as its shell, the other has `/usr/sbin/nologin` - in practical terms, there's no difference.

```
$ getent passwd tftp unbound
tftp:x:182:187:tftp daemon,,,:/srv/tftp:/bin/false
unbound:x:188:210::/var/lib/unbound:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Also, these are often called system users, have a UID < 1000, and have no home directory.

Comment: Most will have a home directory and it will be owned by their UID, just not usually under `/home`...technically they **all** have a home dir (as the 6th field of a passwd entry is the home dir), but sometimes it'll be something like `/nonexistent` or some other directory which doesn't exist (e.g. see `getent passwd | grep /nonexistent`).    In the examples shown in my answer, `tftp`'s home dir is `/srv/tftp` and `unbound`'s is `/var/lib/unbound`